# SocialMediaData["Twitter"]: no output

Tags: social-media

I decided to give the `SocialMediaData` functionality of MMA10 a try but it does not seem to work for Twitter. The first time I call `SocialMediaData[]` I am correctly forwarded to the Twitter website where I can copy my authorization key, but then nothing happens. This is, for example, the output I get for

```
SocialMediaData["Twitter","FollowerNetwork"]
```

[image]

When I enter a wrong authorization key the authorization window keeps reappearing so apparently the key is correct.
`SocialMediaData` for Facebook works like it should.

**Question: what could be the reason that SocialMediaData does not give any output?**

Comment: Can replicate on v10 Windows 8.1.

Comment: It works for me on V10 OS X.

Comment: Good point, my OS is Debian 7

Comment: Apparently there is no quick solution to this problem. I will ask Wolfram support en report back here.

Comment: Wolfram Support replied that they have forwarded my question and that they are aware of the fact that SocialMediaData[] is not functioning properly. No solution yet...

Comment: The issue is fixed in the new paclet release of Social Media Data. For more information see [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97287/socialmediadatatwitter-strange-output)