# SocialMediaData["Twitter"] - strange output

Tags: import, social-media

I am getting error messages when I use `SocialMediaData["Twitter"]`:

```
In[10]:= SocialMediaData["Twitter", "Followers"] // Short

During evaluation of In[10]:= ImportString::string: First argument {https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?oauth_consumer_key=tbAI77cpAHuGjwQnZFQFcQ&oauth_nonce=7twtOf0eBCi4P4GQAQKcvhSZOoYV4&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA\[Ellipsis] 776772%2C2374341553%2C1909504597%2C3351053884%2C3277771244%2C9337792%2C19703707%2C14607461%2C2659808059%2C18771160&oauth_signature=hO7dYANpNmD0BHXRCAUr7NG9SXQ%3D,<<1>>,<<1>>} is not a string. >>

During evaluation of In[10]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {<<1>>} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

During evaluation of In[10]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {ImportString[{https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?oauth_consumer_key=tbAI77cpAHuGjwQnZFQFcQ&oauth_nonce=7twtOf0eBCi4P4GQAQKcvhSZOoYV4&oauth_signature_me\[Ellipsis] 44%2C9337792%2C19703707%2C14607461%2C2659808059%2C18771160&oauth_signature=hO7dYANpNmD0BHXRCAUr7NG9SXQ%3D, VerifyPeer -> False, CredentialsProvider -> None}, JSON]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

During evaluation of In[10]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {<<1>>} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

During evaluation of In[10]:= General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Out[10]//Short= \!\(
TagBox[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"\<\"273767098\"\>", ",", "\<\"17352618\"\>", 
     ",", "\<\"42417984\"\>", ",", "\<\"15128484\"\>", ",", 
RowBox[{"<<", "776", ">>"}], ",", "\<\"14369724\"\>", 
     ",", "\<\"14183055\"\>", ",", "\<\"3730611\"\>"}], "}"}],
Short]\)
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what went wrong here?

Comment: I would be wary of posting things like your OAuth keys in public places. Yes, there's a nonce, but it's still a bit scary.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Recently issues related to SocialMediaData(for services like Twitter/Facebook) has been fixed with new paclet release.

[image]